# TFS. The analogue of Build with Parameters in Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, tfs

I am starting to use TFS, but I've had some experience with Jenkins.
Does TFS(2015) have any analog mechanism as Jenkins -> Build with Parameters?

So, what I need is to have the predefined set of parameters to choose for VS test build step.

Comment: What's the detailed parameters you'd like to use for VS Test step?

Comment: It is the list of strings, which I would like to define in drop-down: this is the list of pages I would like to run my tests agains.
We use Specflow+SpecRun and the string in droip-down will be associated with appropriate tag in my tests feature files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are using vNext build. If you want to set the test run parameters in VS test build step, you can save them in .RunSettings file and choose the .RunSettings file in VS Test step. And there is also an "Override TestRun Parameters" option which allow you to enter the test paremeters. Refer to this link for details: [Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/).
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Eddie - MSFT, but what am I looking for is the way to define the list of values to choose from combo-box or drop-down.
It's because we want business-level persons be able to trigger our tests against appropriate pages which are marked in feature files with appropriate tags. 
If we use suggested approach they still need know the hardcoded names of tags, and this is redundant knowledge for them.
But I think, we can use the set of run.settings to create each configuration for each page.

Comment: @VitaliSonchyk There isn't any way to achieve this with the VS Test step. You need to create a custom build task and add a "pickList" input in the task for this. You can refer to this link for details: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/developing-a-custom-build-vnext-task-part-1

Comment: @VitaliSonchyk According to your comments, you can also define them in the variables and they just need to enter the parameter names. I added an image in my answer, let me know if it can meet your requirement.

Comment: many thanks, I appreciate your suggestion with variables, seems like this approach is suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the feature you are looking for is similar to [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds). The api to queue a build is as below:

```
POST http(s)://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}
```